# How can I make a Tkinter GUI that auto fills certain entries

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, user-input

I am trying to make a GUI with Tkinter that allows you to enter either a URL or an ID.

Example URL: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10030860/1/The-Final-Battle
Example ID: 10030860

As you can see, the ID is embedded in the URL. I want to have two entries, one for entering a URL and one for entering an ID. If a user fills in the URL box, the ID is automatically generated. (If I put the example URL in the URL entry box, I want the example ID in the ID box automatically generated and vice versa) If a user fills in the ID box, the URL is automatically generated.

More examples: (The brackets are pretending to entry boxes)

```
URL: [https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10030860/1/The-Final-Battle] <-- If I fill this in
ID:  [10030860] <-- Python fills this in for me
```

```
URL: [https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10030860/1/The-Final-Battle] <-- Python fills this in for me
ID:  [10030860] <-- If I fill this in
```

Here is my code so far:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Define a function to autofill in the URL and ID entries
def autofill_id_url():
    fanfic_url.set("https://www.fanfiction.net/s/" + fanfic_id.get() + "/1/")
    root.after(100, autofill_id_url)

# Root window
root = tk.Tk()

# Define the labeled frame where we input stuff
input_frame = tk.LabelFrame(master=root, text="Input")
input_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1, rowspan=2, sticky=tk.NS)

# Label for entering URL
ttk.Label(master=input_frame, text="URL:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
# Entry field for URL
fanfic_url = tk.StringVar()
url_entry = ttk.Entry(master=input_frame, textvariable=fanfic_url)
url_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

# Label for entering ID
ttk.Label(master=input_frame, text="ID:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
# Entry field for ID
fanfic_id = tk.StringVar()
id_entry = ttk.Entry(master=input_frame, textvariable=fanfic_id)
id_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

# Start callback functions
autofill_id_url()

# Start GUI event loop
root.mainloop()
```

I have the part when you fill in the ID, the URL is generated automatically. But I have *no idea* how to make it when you fill in the URL box, you get the ID box filled in for you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trace_variable` method of `StringVar` to do autofill. *The following code will do so but this is just a basic code to get started as it will require some more work to implement autofill perfectly.*

```py
after_ids = {}

def get_url(id_):
    """returns url from id."""
    url = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/{}/1/The-Final-Battle'
    return url.format(id_)

def get_id(url):
    """returns id from the url."""
    l = url.split('/')
    return l[4] if len(l) > 4 else ''

def autofill_entry(mode, dalay=1000):
    """Auto-fills Url/ID."""
    for v in after_ids.values():
        root.after_cancel(v)
    if mode == 'url':  
        id_ = get_id(fanfic_url.get())
        after_ids[0] = root.after(dalay, lambda: fanfic_id.set(id_))
    elif mode == 'id':
        url = get_url(fanfic_id.get())
        after_ids[1] = root.after(dalay, lambda: fanfic_url.set(url))
```

Now assign the function `autofill_entry` to the entry widgets StringVars.

```py
fanfic_url.trace_variable('w', lambda *a: autofill_entry('url'))
fanfic_id.trace_variable('w', lambda *a: autofill_entry('id'))
```

Also, I would recommend you use [`from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to join URL and fetch id from the URL.

Comment: Although it could work, but I don't recommend to use the code `[root.after_cancel(v) for v in after_ids.values()]`. It is not necessary to increase the memory usage in order to reduce the lines of code.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA: if you mean `for v in after_ids.values(): root.after_cancel(v)` then I don't see a difference as I'm not creating any variable to store `[root.after_cancel(v) for v in after_ids.values()]`. *(Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong :) )*

Comment: Yes ,both of them could work.Your code created a list but didn't assign it to a variable.When python evaluate this code, it would waste unnecessary memory overhead.(Not a big problem but I think it is not a good practice).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! I already have code that fetches URLS with `requests` and use `bs4` to parse and it works quite well for someone who just started learning to web scrap stuff. May I ask, why do you use this syntax: `lambda *a: ` Is the `*` necessary?

Comment: I'm just not that familiar with `lambda` I know that define a function on the fly like you have done here: `lambda: fanfic_id.set(id_)`. But is the `*` significant?

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino: By default, a variable trace method passes 3 arguments to the callback function so [`*a`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) parameter will take all those 3 arguments passed by `trace_variable`. You can read this [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/)  and scroll down to the code to understand those 3 arguments.

Comment: You can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771787/10364425) on `lambda` function as a command in Tkinter to get a better understanding.

Comment: So it passes these three arguments `var, indx, mode` like from the code?

Comment: I also do know that you can pass in `lambda` to `tkinter` so that you can pass in parameter to the function you want to execute. (I really do need to use theme more though) EDIT: Like `ttk.Button(master=root, text="Hi", command=lambda: print("Hi"))`

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino: Yes, but as we are not using these parameters, so I decide to make *one autofill function for both the traces* and used lambda to define a difference with parameter `mode`.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks! (Ok, now SO is telling to move this discussion to the chat)

Answer (score 2):

Better do the auto fill when <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed in the entry box instead of using `.after()`.

```
baseurl = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/'

def autofill_url_id(_):
    try:
        # extract the id from the url
        url = fanfic_url.get().strip()
        if url.startswith(baseurl):
            id = url.split('/')[4]
            fanfic_id.set(id)
    except IndexError:
        print('failed to extract id from the url')

def autofill_id_url(_):
    id = fanfic_id.get().strip()
    if id:
        fanfic_url.set(baseurl+id+'/1/')
...
# Start callback functions
#autofill_id_url()
url_entry.bind('<Return>', autofill_url_id)
id_entry.bind('<Return>', autofill_id_url)
```